# EntryPointNotFoundException on Windows XP with Windows API Code Pack

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to use the MS Windows API Code Pack in my application.

```
string docRef = @"adocument.docx";
var shellFile = Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.ShellFile.FromFilePath(docRef);
```

It works fine with Windows 7, while it raises an error with Windows XP (with installed .NET 3.5):

> "System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'SHCreateItemFromParsingName' in DLL 'shell32.dll'."

What do I need to do to launch MS WACP on Windows XP?

Answer (score 4):

This method has been introduced in Windows Vista and doesn't exist in Windows XP. See [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
The Windows API Code pack exists to allow you managed access to Windows 7 and - I think - Windows Vista features. These features simply don't exist in Windows XP, so you can't use them.

Answer (score 1):

The API Code Pack relies on Windows 7 *only* API's, so they are not valid on Windows XP.  You need to check the version of the operating system, and execute alternate code if it's not Windows 7 (or presumably Windows 8 now).